# How to pass parameters to URL from Laravel Blade file

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I want to pass parameters from my blade file to the URL when the user presses the next or previous button. I want to achieve that when the user presses the button next, the parameters `page` will be equal to 1, and the value will keep increasing by one every time the user presses the following button. I know I have to do something in `ref,` but I do not know what code to put in. So the example URL after the user presses the next button will be `www.example.com?page=1`.

```
<div>
    <ul class="pagination">
        <li class="">
            <a href=""><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i> Previous</a>
        </li>
        <li class="">
            <a href="">Next <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Can't you use the model's blade pagination helper `{{$model->links()}}`?

Comment: I have done the pagination thing in my controller and I would like to pass the page parameters to the link and everything will work fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like options you can learn about [generating URLs to Named Routes](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#generating-urls-to-named-routes).
With this helper you can past URL in your blade

```
<a herf="{{ route('name_your_route', ['page' => 2]) }}">test</a>
```

If need more logic you can write in `@php` section, but its not good

If you need rewrite (redisign) standart pagination you can do this with [customizing pagination view](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/pagination#customizing-the-pagination-view)

Comment: Thanks this work fine, and it is what I am looking for

Answer (score 1):

You can use Laravel default pagination such as

```
$users = User::paginate(15);
```

and use them in the blade such as

```
{{ $users->links() }}
```

There are many pagination option such as simplepaginate and other u can explore them as well
hope this would be helpfull

Comment: I have done the pagination thing in my controller and I would like to pass the page parameters to the link and everything will work fine

Comment: can you please post the code of the pagination ..

Comment: It is not possible for me to post the code as it is not my work. But what I want to do is to pass the parameter to the URL. I think there is nothing to do with the code of pagination

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to display simple "Next" and "Previous" links in your application's UI, you may use the `simplePaginate` method to perform a single, efficient query:

```
$users = DB::table('users')->simplePaginate(15);
```

By default, the views rendered to display the pagination links are compatible with the Tailwind CSS framework.

However, the easiest way to customize the pagination views is by exporting them to your `resources/views/vendor` directory using the `vendor:publish` command:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-pagination
```